# Show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

The book I'm reading outlines the proof:

Let $x_0 > 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

WTS: $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ when $|x - x_0|$ is small.

Now reducing $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = \frac{(x_0 - x)(x_0 + x)}{x^2x_0^2}$.

Then it says if $|x - x_0| < \frac{x_0}{2}$

$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \frac{10|x_0 - x|}{x_0^3}$. Now let $\delta =$ min${{\frac{x_0}{2}, \frac{x_0^3\epsilon}{10}}}$

But why did they originally choose $|x - x_0| < \frac{x_0}{2}$? I don't see how I could have formulated that guess if I was doing the proof on my own. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$|x-x_0| <x_0/2 \implies x_0/2 < x < 3x_0/2$$

Hence

$$(x+x_0)/x^2 < (x_0 + 3x_0/2)(2/x_0)^2 =10/x_0^3$$

The choice is somewhat arbitrary.  You simply want to get an upper bound for $1/x^2$ in terms of $x_0$ when $x$ is sufficiently close to $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now.

Comment: @M.Smith: You're welcome.